# Lining up numerous gunshots

Tags: sound-design, workflow

Am doing a film with a lot of gun shots (single, semi-automatic, automatic). Was wondering some ideas on workflows. Drop in single gun shots into kontakt, drop in a marker at each muzzle flash or click sound,  and line up the midi notes? Or perhaps detect hit points, make a midi "groove" and line up the midi notes that way. Or better to just use audio and line up each gunshot that way? Am looking for the fastest, most automated workflow. I'm using Nuendo 6.

Answer (score 2):

Automating it might be good for a first pass, but imho everything needs finessing as individual sound cues - whether background or foreground - and I find that more difficult & less satisfying via MIDI, prefer seeing the waveforms especially when layering elements where the attack has to be acutely accurately aligned...

I know its not Nuendo but in PT I marked up sync for each scene using memory location markers, and then set the grid to follow/snap to the markers so it became a non linear grid. This amde it faster for a first pass & when layering elements... but still had to get detailed to bring them to life...

Comment: Agreed. It will need finessing for sure. Thanks for the thoughts. 

Answer (score 1):

> Am looking for the fastest, most automated workflow.

I think the most automated workflow that doesn't have the risk of sounding too bad because of phase cancellation or bad timing is to load all gunshot samples to a sampler, route them to individual outputs, create tracks for recording every output, press record and play a few layered gunshots from the MIDI keyboard. Then select the best one and crop it, do quick adjustments, if needed, and there you have it. No guarantees that it'll result in the best gunshot sound or the kind of gunshot that you'd like though.

Answer (score 0):

I would drop markers for each gunshot and tracklay each one separately. It might take longer, but you will have more control later. The idea of having stuff running through Kontakt sounds like a mixing nightmare (if you have multiple shots coming form one instance), or a waste of processing power (if you run multiple instances). I think any time you save in the tracklay will be lost in the mix when you come to setting up panning, eq and reverb. Also, if you need to return to the session later you are dependent on Kontakt running properly - best to have the audio itself locked in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Good preparation and set-up with Kontakt can be a very effective way. In addition, it can be used for other projects.

Drop all shots in Kontakt. One instrument for one type of gun. Drop all instruments in a Multi-Instrument, save the Multi, record MIDI on several tracks with the appropriate MIDI channel, edit, bounce to audio.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Will post back when I have a macro and workflow. Thanks for the responses.